# Is there any way to add a "custom field" to the CPT archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

as per my title I have a CPT with an archive.

I'd like to have my archive main page (the back end) displaying two custom fields that would allow me specifying the "meta tag description" and "page title" for the archive page itself (and not the single post underneath).
Clearly I can't add a custom field per se, so I was wondering what other solution it may be available?

Would the metabox fit the bill?

EDIT: reading some of the comment below, I suspect I need to make a change in the "core", but this is something a bit more complicated.

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Are you talking about the front or the back end?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this code wise but you could dig through the "WordPress SEO by Yoast" plugin to see how he does it. Or use a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields to add custom fields for your category/archive pages which could then be displayed via your theme.

Comment: @s_ha_dum the output is for the front end, but the interface should be in the back end.

Comment: @Michelle the advanced custome field plugin - which I use - allow to create a CF for a specific post type but there is anything that binds to the "back end" of the archive page.

Comment: You have been posting quite a lot of questions regarding this topic if my mind serves me well. (This is no propblem, lol.) I think I have suggested to you before, but if I didn't, I would suggest you to use a custom page.php template rather than an archive.php template. As far as I know, there is no backend interface  for archive and category pages. I do think that a custom page.php template are more useful and have far less retrictions that an archive.php template

Comment: Are [these](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_list_table) anything like what you want?

Comment: @AndreaMoro, yes, in the area where it says "show this field group when" select "Taxonomy Term" from the drop down and then either choose the category/tag or just 'all'. I think this tutorial might help with what you're doing: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/

Comment: Hey @PieterGoosen you are right I have posted quite a lot, but no I didn't get that suggestion before. It's too late now to waste all the work I've done and move to a custom page template :(. Isn't there any other solution?

Comment: @Michelle that video / tutorial, which I've seen, explain how to use ACF to create an archive with a front-end group of checkboxes to pass an argument to reload and filter the results on the page. This is not what I'm after. I don't need any interaction from the front-end.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think another possible solution it may be embedding a post with the get_posts function. What do u think about this?

Comment: @Michelle what it could be made with ACF is importing the CF from another page using the the_field function whilst specifying the page name. Have a look here http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/code-examples/

Comment: Yep you could do that. You might want to buy the cheap "Options" add-on for ACF so you can keep those fields separate.

Comment: Yes I already purchased that plugin, and that may represent another solution at which I didn't think initially. Thk @Michelle